# Get a DB result with a value between two column values

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database situation where I'd like to get a user profile row by a user age range.

this is my db:

```
table_users
username     age     email                     url
pippo        15      example@example.com       http://example.com
pluto        33      example@example.com       http://example.com
mikey        78      example@example.com       http://example.com


table_profiles
p_name       start_age_range      stop_age_range
young        10                   29
adult        30                   69
old          70                   inf
```

I use `MySQL` and `PHP` but I don't know if there is some specific tacnique to do this and of course if it's possible.

```
# so something like:
SELECT *
FROM table_profiles AS profiles
INNER JOIN table_users AS users
# can I do something like this?
ON users.age IS BETWEEN profiles.start_age_range AND profiles.stop_age_range
```

Comment: Why store a constantly changing value in a database? Wouldn't date of birth be more appropriate?

Comment: Have you tried removing the IS from IS BETWEEN? Using SQL Server, it is a valid SQL statement.

Comment: @symcbean you are right, I currently store a date, I've used a simple number in this example to simplify my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select
  *
From
  table_profiles As profiles,
  table_users As users
Where
  users.age Between profiles.start_age_rage And profiles.stop_age_range
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
    SELECT *
    FROM table_profiles AS profiles
    Where 
 users.age >= profiles.start_age_range AND users.age <=profiles.stop_age_range
```

Comment: 'INNER JOIN <table alias> ON <boolean>' isn't legal SQL for any database.